# orderby price meta_value which contains comma - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, sql-order-by

I have posts which should be sorted by price custom field (from high to low). Used below options to order them correctly:

**OPTION 1**

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'my-post-type', 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'price_field',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
);
$list = get_posts($args);
```

**OPTION 2**

```
global $wpdb;
$queryStr = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts AS table1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE 
meta_key = 'price_field') AS table2 ON table1.ID = table2.post_id WHERE 
table1.post_type = 'my-post-type' AND table1.post_status = 'publish' order by 
table2.meta_value+0 DESC";
$list = $wpdb->get_results($queryStr);
```

**OPTION 3** (same as option 2 just with REPLACE function)

```
$queryStr = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts AS table1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE 
meta_key = 'price_field') AS table2 ON table1.ID = table2.post_id WHERE 
table1.post_type = 'my-post-type' AND table1.post_status = 'publish' order by 
REPLACE(table2.meta_value, ',', '') DESC";
```

Posts are being ordered as follows (in wrong order):

```
600
25,000
22,000
15,000
10,000
7,000
6,000
2,000
0
```

Sorting was good until I added post with `600` price. As long as it doesn't have comma in it, it appeared at the very start of the loop which is not correct.

Is there something that I missed?

Comment: Well the wrong thing here might rather be that you stored _formatted_ numbers in the first place ... If you wanted to use them for sorting, you should have stored them as integers, and only insert a thousand separator when you _output_ those values ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could build a valid order  using  a (fake) lpad in the order by clause eg:

```
$queryStr = "SELECT * 
             FROM wp_posts AS table1 
             LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
             FROM wp_postmeta 
             WHERE meta_key = 'price_field') AS table2 ON table1.ID = table2.post_id 
             WHERE  table1.post_type = 'my-post-type' AND table1.post_status = 'publish' 
             order by  lpad(table2.meta_value, 12, '0') ASC";
```

Reference:-

[String Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

Or  based on fact you have signbe you could try convert

```
$queryStr = "SELECT * 
             FROM wp_posts AS table1 
             LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                  FROM wp_postmeta 
                  WHERE meta_key = 'price_field') AS table2 ON table1.ID = table2.post_id 
             WHERE  table1.post_type = 'my-post-type' AND table1.post_status = 'publish' 
             order by  CONVERT(REPLACE(table2.meta_value, ',', ''),SIGNED INTEGER) ASC";
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. `lpad` seems ordered perfectly all posts except one post which price is 4,000 and it appeared at the very start of the order which is again wrong. So order looks like this: 4,000 - 25,000 - 22,000 - 15,000 - 10,000

Comment: table2.meta_value type is longtext, it doesn't have numeric type @scaisEdge